# Laravel 5.2 stateless authentication with guard ['admin','client' ] for multi auth in api

Tags: laravel-5

please help me,

I want the stateless authentication for Rest api for login api to to get the token from it by using guard in it.

Comment: laravel 5.2 stateless authentication for api using guard driver.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using Laravel Lumen because laravel by default uses session state.

In lumen you can be able to authenticate a user by using the new Auth::viaRequest() method. Docs here: https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication

Comment: I am facing difficulties on implementing the stateless authentication for rest api using
1.) Email and password
2.) Token after login attempt.

please provide me some tutorial